# AngularJS prevent Flash of unstyled content (FOUC) with angular-css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm currently using angular-css to inject css dynamically in head tag when I click on a link, but I see a flash of unstyled content. If I put css in the login.html file, I don't have this problem. I tried to add ng-cloak on entire login.html file but it's not working (but ng-cloak works correctly for the first load).

Is there a way to dynamically load css without FOUC using angularJS and angular-css ?

Is it a bad practice to put css above html in style tag ? This can resolve the problem and reduce the number of requests made by the browser.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix it by using ng-cloak and adding the following to your index.html file

```
[ng:cloak], 
[ng-cloak], 
[data-ng-cloak], 
[x-ng-cloak], 
.ng-cloak, 
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```